# Can't open chrome with command line in Centos

Tags: google-chrome, centos6

I just installed chrome on my CentOS 6.7, following instructions [here](http://tecadmin.net/install-google-chrome-in-centos-rhel-and-fedora/#). The install seems to have completed, but I couldn't open chrome with the following command:

```
$google-chrome
```

It just does not do anything. If I try:

```
$google-chrome &
```

I get

```
[1]27033
```

And I did all these as a non-root user. Any input will be much appreciated!

Comment: google-chrome --no-sandbox

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this steps from this link:
[Open Chrome from centos](http://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/centos-how-tos/how-to-run-google-chrome-as-root-fedora-16-centos-6-rhel-6.html)

Comment: It's not really my primary concern here to open chrome as a root vs. a normal user, but I tried the method in the post anyways, but I got `Aborted` when I ran `google-chrome`.

Comment: @JJ.Y , It could be an issue with your gpu or its drivers try this command in your terminal  `google-chrome-stable  --disable-gpu`  also go through this [https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-discuss/luDLT9Jbvgg]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but that still didn't fix the problem.